# How do I fix one to many relationship where one side has two entities of the same type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, one-to-many, ef-fluent-api

I am working on a project. When I first started, I had an Order Model and Address Model. Now, however, I would like to change the Order Model to have AddressTo and AddressFrom instead of just Address.

Address Model:

```
public class Address
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public int ZipCodeId { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public int Nr { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Order { get; set; }
    public virtual ZipCode ZipCode { get; set; }
}
```

Order Model:

```
public class Order
{   
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; } 
    public DateTime SentDate { get; set; } 
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int ExpectedHours { get; set; }
    public int AmountWorkers { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer{ get; set; }
}
```

What I want in Order:

```
public class Order
{   
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Address AddressTo { get; set; }
    public virtual Address AddressFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; } 
    public DateTime SentDate { get; set; } 
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int ExpectedHours { get; set; }
    public int AmountWorkers { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer{ get; set; }
}
```

I have realized that solving this problem without `FluentApi` is not possible. However, I am finding it difficult to overcome this problem.

What I want is my Order table in the database to show ID columns `AddressToId` and `AddressFromId`, as opposed to just `AddressId` (that's how it is right now).

Would really appreciate help from the community on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove  `public virtual ICollection<Order> Order { get; set; }` navigation property from your `Address` model class as follows:

```
public class Address
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public int ZipCodeId { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public int Nr { get; set; }

    public virtual ZipCode ZipCode { get; set; }
}
```

Then add  `AddressFromId` and `AddressToId` properties to your `Order` model class as follows:

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    ..............
    public int AddressFromId { get; set; }
    public virtual Address AddressFrom { get; set; }

    public int AddressToId { get; set; }
    public virtual Address AddressTo { get; set; }

    ................
}
```

Then your `Order` Configuration as follows:

```
public class OrderConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Order>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Order> builder)
    {
        builder.HasOne(o => o.AddressFrom).WithMany().HasForeignKey(o => o.AddressFromId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        builder.HasOne(o => o.AddressTo).WithMany().HasForeignKey(o => o.AddressToId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    }
}
```

Then in the `OnModelCreating` of the `DbContext` as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

     modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new OrderConfiguration());  
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I am getting this error when I try your solution. An error occurred while accessing the IWebHost on class 'Program'. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Address.Order' of type 'ICollection<Order>'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Comment: @Endkey You have not removed `public virtual ICollection<Order> Order { get; set; }` from `Address` model class? Please read my answer thoroughly. I have generated everything perfectly in my side in a test project. So surely it will work for you too.

Comment: I have done that. I was surprised with the error message as well. But this is what I get after following all your steps

Comment: Your solution seems to have worked. I get the columns in the database as I wanted to. There was some problem with the versions and just Visual Studio not getting Metadata files that made Nuget Package Console show the same error again and again. Thanks a lot for your help! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can configure it like this:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  // ...
  modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().HasOne(x => x.AddressTo).WithMany(); //Add HasForeignKey, IsRequired... if you want
  modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().HasOne(x => x.AddressFrom).WithMany(); //Add HasForeignKey, IsRequired... if you want 
  //...
}
```

But do you even need your `Address` to be an entity with id? If not, you can remove `AddressId` and `Order` properties from it, and make it an [owned entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities) of the `Order` entity:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  // ...
  modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().OwnsOne(x => x.AddressTo);
  modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().OwnsOne(x => x.AddressFrom);
  //...
}
```

**Update: Removed Order mapping**

You can remove `Order` property from your `Address` class and just use `.WithMany()` without parameters in your mapping.

Comment: Your these `modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().HasOne(x => x.AddressTo).WithMany(x => x.Order); //Add HasForeignKey, IsRequired... if you want
  modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().HasOne(x => x.AddressFrom).WithMany(x => x.Order);` two lines is completely wrong. You cannot point two foreign keys to a single a navigation property.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. This is the error i get now, using the first solution you provided  An error occurred while accessing the IWebHost on class 'Program'. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Address.Order' of type 'ICollection<Order>'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.